# Argument of extend() must be a List or Dictionary, using List as a String errors

Tags: neovim, lua, plugin-airline

I have next `init.lua` in `~/.config/nvim`

```lua
vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]

require('packer').startup(function(use)
    -- Packer can manage itself
    use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
    
    use 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
    use 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

    vim.g.airline_symbols.colnr = ' col '
end)

vim.cmd.set("background=dark")
vim.cmd.colorscheme("PaperColor")
```

If I open the nvim with this I get

```
Error detected while processing /Users/vladyslav/dotfiles/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...e/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim/lua/packer.lua:1023: /Users/vladyslav/dotfiles/nvim/init.lua:68: attempt to index field 'airline_symbols' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        ...e/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim/lua/packer.lua:1023: in function 'startup'
        /Users/vladyslav/dotfiles/nvim/init.lua:55: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Okay, I change my `init.lua` to

```lua
vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]

require('packer').startup(function(use)
    -- Packer can manage itself
    use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
    
    use 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
    use 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

     if vim.g.airline_symbols == nil then
        vim.g.airline_symbols = {}
     end

    vim.g.airline_symbols.colnr = ' col '
end)

vim.cmd.set("background=dark")
vim.cmd.colorscheme("PaperColor")
```

And if I run it I get

[image]

And finally, if I do

```lua
vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]

require('packer').startup(function(use)
    -- Packer can manage itself
    use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
    
    use 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
    use 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

     if vim.g.airline_symbols == nil then
        vim.g.airline_symbols = {colnr = ' col '}
     end
end)

vim.cmd.set("background=dark")
vim.cmd.colorscheme("PaperColor")
```

, then everything is ok.

What is happening? How to set `vim.g.airline_symbols` from `init.lua` not inside `if` as a table?

Answer (score 2):

There is a kind of misunderstanding here.

1. `vim.g.foo.a = 0` will fail as `foo` does not exist (yet). This is quite common point for many languages, no matter if Lua or VimScript.
2. `vim.g.foo = {}; vim.g.foo.a = 0` will fail, because empty Lua table is converted to empty VimScript List that cannot be indexed by string.
3. `vim.g.foo = {a=1}; vim.g.foo.b = 2` kinda works but... not really. This is because `vim.g` is a special one that has metatable with `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods. While `vim.g.foo` is an ordinary variable that does not have any of them. And so one can do `vim.cmd("let foo={a:1}"); t = vim.g.foo; t.b = 2` but changing `t` will never affect value of `foo` in VimScript. This is one of those old and well-known pitfalls that every newbie inevitably falls into.

Answer (score 1):

See the [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/15hsqls/comment/juqf5dy/?context=3) for origin.

> `:h lua-vim-variables`
> Note that setting dictionary fields directly will not write them back into
> Nvim. This is because the index into the namespace simply returns a copy.
> Instead the whole dictionary must be written as one. This can be achieved by
> creating a short-lived temporary.
> Example:

```
vim.g.my_dict.field1 = 'value'  -- Does not work

local my_dict = vim.g.my_dict   --
my_dict.field1 = 'value'        -- Instead do
vim.g.my_dict = my_dict         --
```

this is why your final method works. you can just remove the if.

Comment: Seems like a weird design choice for NeoVim to make. Thanks for giving us this answer, though!